# Regular expression to find text between strings WITHOUT a predefined string in the middle

Tags: regex, string, find, regex-negation

I've a so written text:

```
11 bla gulp bla 22
11 bla bla bla 2211 bla 
ble
bli 22
```

I need a regex to find all the text between **all** the couples "`11`" and "`22`" BUT that **DON'T** contain "`gulp`".

If I search `(?s)11.*?22` using TextCrawler, I find all the three strings:

```
bla gulp bla
bla bla bla
bla ble bli
```

Wrong! I'd like to obtain only:

```
bla bla bla
bla ble bli
```

because "`bla gulp bla`" contains "`gulp`", and I don't want it!

Any idea? :-)

Comment: What implementation are you using?  JS?  PHP?

Comment: @acheong87 - TextCrawler was mentioned, so I'm assuming that the manual page on the web for that program is accurate in saying " TextCrawler implements VBScript /  JavaScript ECMA-262 regular expressions."

Comment: @CodeJockey - Ah, I mistook TextCrawler for a kind of regex tester/aid. Good research!

Answer (score 1):

use a negative lookahead assertion:

```
11(?!.*?gulp.*?)(.*?)22
```

word boundaries might be a good idea in the middle (surrounding `gulp`), because it would allow to distinguish between `gulp` and `gulping`, `gulped` or `ungulp`(?):

```
11(?!.*?\bgulp\b.*?)(.*?)22
```

but putting them around everything:

```
\b11\b(?!.*?\bgulp\b.*?)(.*?)\b22\b
```

would exclude your other two results - not what you want.

Comment: If you were me and I were you, I would have kindly edited your solution and/or added comments for clarification, rather than pollute the space with near-identical answers. But I suppose "in the hunt for reputation" people do things that aren't always in the best interests of the community ;-) (Yes, I do see that you added a non-greedy quantifier, which I added as well in my edit, and you have a good point about word boundaries, but personally I thought OP might have oversimplified the problem and could find use for them, as you further clarified.  Thank you.)

Comment: @acheong87 While my comment was curt to be sure, I have in the past and do often comment about such things rather than offer my own answer. But when an answer seems to have been given quickly, but with more than 1 or 2 (what I perceive to be) errors (no capturing group on two expressions, greedy quantifiers, inappropriate word boundary assertions, using inline JavaScript syntax [`//`] for a text editor, and possibly more), I find it easier to simply make my own answer and perhaps point out the more egregious error(s). Testing would have highlighted your errors.

Comment: @acheong87 I don't think that I "hunt for reputation", but it's hard to see one's self. Sometimes, a faster answer is better (that is, more useful to the OP). Sometimes a more thought out, carefully crafted, more thoroughly tested answer is preferred. Both types of answers (and answer providers) are represented on the site and neither is particularly discouraged by the reputation model

Comment: Good points, esp. regarding the greedy quantifiers (the rigor of my answers sometimes depend on the rigor of the questions); I don't deny your solution is more complete. However, in light of my stated (general) purpose--to introduce the concepts OP needed--I feel you are being a bit argumentative. It's not your duty to be polite of course. It just seems pedantic to argue, rather than to open your imagination to understand, that perhaps I left out capturing groups _to follow OP's own example_; and perhaps I use ``//`` (Perl, sed, vi, etc.) as a "language hint," like ``<?php ?>``.

Comment: Anyway, I know you mean well, and I meant well in my own way. Deleting my solution; upvoting yours. All the best.